# Import external definitions

Tags: typescript, typescript1.4

With Typescript, is there a way to import just the types from an external module?

Basically I just want one module to know the typings from another (to power Intellisense), but without the import being emitted in JavaScript. I want to do this because the module in question may or may not have been loaded - i.e. there isn't a hard dependency, but I want to have some typed code that runs and uses the module if it is there.

Hope this is clear.

Answer (score 10):

You can use a definition file along with a reference comment, which makes the types available without adding any import statements (such as `require` or `define`).

```
///<reference path="module.d.ts" />
```

You can automatically generate definition files during compilation, although for your purposes you'll probably want to hand-crank a custom one (depends on how you want to use it - the automatic one will expect to be imported).

## Example Code

*ModuleA.ts*

```
class ExampleOne {
    doSomething() {
        return 5;
    }
}

export = ExampleOne;
```

*ModuleB.ts*

```
class ExampleTwo {
    doSomething() {
        return 'str';
    }
}

export = ExampleTwo;
```

Intended use:

```
import B = require('moduleb');

var a = new ExampleOne();
var b = new B();
```

To make this work, you would create your *ModuleA.d.ts*:

*ModuleA.d.ts*

```
declare class ExampleOne {
    doSomething(): number;
}
```

And then reference it like so:

```
/// <reference path="modulea.d.ts" />

import B = require('moduleb');

var a = new ExampleOne();
var b = new B();
```

Comment: I didn't think this worked with external modules? I thought it was internal only. I'll give it a go when I can!

Comment: I have expanded with an example to show how to do this.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work, but unfortunately the auto-generated .d.ts files include the 'export = ' line which seems to prevent the types coming through. I'll raise this on GitHub.

Comment: The auto-generated one will be suited for importing, rather than referencing (which makes sense for the normal use case)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it answers your question, but you can add a type definitions file:

```
/** mytype.d.ts */
interface MyType {
  prop1: number,
  prop2: string
}

export default MyType
```

and import it in both of your modules like this:

```
/** module1.ts */
import MyType from './mytype.d'

//use
let myVar: MyType
```