# How to import interface definitions from the same file name?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a file: `api.ts` and I defined my interfaces in `api.d.ts`. Although when I run typescript it complains about my interface which cannot be found:

> api.ts(24,47): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'IHeaders'.

How can I import my interfaces in my main file when they have the exact same name?

I've tried the following:

```
// api.d.ts

export interface IHeaders {
  [key: string]: string;
}

// api.ts

import { IHeaders } from './api';
```

But I get a different error:

> api.ts(4,10): error TS2305: Module '"api"' has no exported member
>   'IHeaders'.

What's the best approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The point of `.d.ts` files is to provide typing information for legacy Javascript code.

They aren't like C/C++ header files and should not be used with Typescript code.

You should move your interfaces to the main file.

Answer (score 1):

SLaks's answer is correct: you shouldn't introduce `.d.ts` interface files.

Your `api.ts` could look like this

```
export interface IHeaders {
  [key: string]: string;
}

export class Headers implements IHeaders {
   [key: string]: string;
}
```

Usage (`test.ts`):

```
import { Headers, IHeaders } from "./api"

var a = new Headers();
a["x"] = "y";
```

---

**However**, if you really want to use a definintion file, add the following line at the top of the file in which you want to import the declarations:

```
///<reference path="api.d.ts" />
```

You can find a full example [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28397331/7954580).